# GCP container registry suddenly isn't allowing access from anywhere

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a project on GCP and I use the container registry to host our Docker images. Everything was working find until suddenly all service accounts are getting access denied when trying to push/pull images from the registry. I tried accessing it from the web interface and I'm still getting an error saying that I don't have enough permissions even though I'm the organization owner.

Even when I tried to list the images using gcloud I faced the same problem.

> gcloud container images list

> ERROR: (gcloud.container.images.list) Access denied:
> gcr.io/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a billing issue however all services are functioning properly except for the registry, it doesn't mention anything about an outstanding balance it just gives you an access denied error. once I paid the amount it's back to normal.